# Does gulp have code splitting for javascript files?

Tags: javascript, gulp, code-splitting

I'm using gulp and I want to know if it has capabilities for code splitting. Something similar to what is mentioned here in the [webpack site](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) . Ive looked online but not seen anything dedicated to that.

Comment: Not an appropriate question for SO

Comment: You can use [webpack from gulp](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html), so if you really want this feature there's nothing stopping you from doing that.

Comment: I feel this is a good question. Was wondering the same thing. +1

Comment: Sir.Nathan Stassen Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a great question, personally. I may be wrong (please correct me if I am) but since gulp is a **task runner** and not a **code bundler**, I don't think code splitting applies to it. Instead, code splitting would apply to a code bundler like Browserify. WebPack is essentially gulp+browserify+other tools wrapped up in one neat little package.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on the internet [gulp-split-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-split-files), I hope this answers your issue.

As you the author has said in the documentation.

In your gulpfile:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const splitFiles = require("gulp-split-files");

gulp.task("split", function () {
    return gulp.src("superMegaBigCss.css")
    .pipe(splitFiles())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("path/to/dest"));
});
```

This will produce three files:

```
superMegaBigCss-0.css
superMegaBigCss-1.css
superMegaBigCss-2.css
```

I don't think this package is very useful, as it split the code where we place the comment `/*split*/`.

---

Personally, I love using webpack so much, now I use it in most of my projects, I think it is like a butcher where it chops down the files and bundles it up in different ways.